# Ubuntu WSL and MinGW : compatibility /conflicts?

Tags: path, mingw, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am using MinGW on Windows 10 for a while which performs pretty well. I now installed Ubuntu 20.04 over WSL and notice, that the PATH settings seem to somehow overlap. Apparently Ubuntu can "see" the path of some programms in Windows, when searching with the command "`which`" m something I wanted to avoid, since I am seeking a fresh start, isolated from Windows. Has anybody being confronted with similar issues? Thank_you

Comment: Run the command `echo $PATH` and review paths like `/mnt/c...`

Comment: Exactly, they appear as /mnt/c... But can I not hide them in WSL, so that these only apear in Windows over MinGW? I would like to install them separately in WSL for more flexibility. Thanks

Comment: MinGW (bash linux) started to crash more often